# Hazelcast:: Set RingBuffer capacity in Client side

Tags: hazelcast

I am working on the hazelcast ringbuffer data structure.

If I set RingBuffer capacity in member then it is working fine. but I would like to set capacity on the client side based on user requirement. so is there any way to set capacity on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic configuration feature

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#dynamically-adding-data-structure-configuration-on-a-cluster

```
    HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
    Config config = client.getConfig();
    config.addRingBufferConfig(new RingbufferConfig("foo").setCapacity(12345));

    Ringbuffer<Object> ringbuffer = client.getRingbuffer("foo");
```

Remember that you cannot update/alter a current configuration but you can add new ones

Comment: Thank you @Ali. This solution is working fine for me.